# Which type of pointer to use to implement shared access to elements of a set?

Tags: c++, pointers, set, immutability, shared-ptr

In order to make the discussion clear, I'm going to describe the problem in a very general manner, i.e. I will neither provide names of real classes nor will I describe the domain/context (however, I might if it turns out to be urgent).

Imagine class `A`. Let this class have 2 **immutable** fields, for instance `x` and `y` (please, notice, that these could be potentially **big** objects, i.e. inefficient to copy). Additionally, let these `x` and `y` be **primary** fields, i.e. only they are used in the implementation of `==`/`!=` operators as well as hash-computing function.

Since `A` is **immutable** in terms of `x` and `y`, the idea is to let multiple instances of `A` (say `a1` and `a2`) which have `a1.x == a2.x` `a1.y == a2.y` (i.e. `a1 == a2`) to **implicitly** have shared access to those `x` and `y`, so that there is no unnecessary duplication.

Moreover, now imagine that there is another field in `A`: `z`, which is **secondary** and **mutable**, and serves as a sort of behavior tweak for `A`. By design, it is desired to make this field shared among **equal** instances of `A` **too**. So, if I invoke `a1.setZ(...)` this change will also affect `a2` because their access to `z` is **shared**.

As a result, we end up with a class `A` which has pure **value semantics**, but shares its members **implicitly** across equal instances. AFAIK such pattern is called [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) or **aliasing**.

One more detail before we move to the question. Most classes in the project are implemented using **Pimpl** idiom:

```
private:
  class Private;

  Private* p;
```

and class `A` is not an exclusion. That's why the proposed idea of implementing the scheme described above is as follows.

1. Use **shared pointer** to `A::Private` instead of raw one in
   **Pimpl** idiom;
2. Have global set of **shared pointers** to `A::Private`;
3. In constructor of `A` to check whether a **shared
   pointer** to suitable `A::Private` already exists in the set
   (utilizing `x` and `y` of course), and if yes, then simply set `p`
   to it, otherwise create new instance of `A::Private` and store
   **shared pointer** to it in this set, and similarly set `p` to it;
4. `A::Private`'s destructor should remove **shared pointer** to `this` from the set.

This looks like the most straightforward and intuitive implementation. However, the problem is that since this global set holds a **shared pointer** to `A::Private`, it means that even when all instances of corresponding `A` are destroyed, the reference counter will stay on `1`, i.e. it will never reach `0`, and thus the memory is never freed.

I thought it would be good if some **shared pointers** would offer a method to set lower bound for the reference counter. In this case, for example, I would simply set it to `1` which would mean that when it reaches `1` it frees the memory. Unfortunately, I haven't found any implementation of such behavior in popular libraries (Boost, Qt, Poco, etc.). Of course, I could do manual reference counting for my problem, but that just doesn't feel right and smells like reinventing the wheel.

Probably, there are other ways to solve this problem. Looking forward for your suggestions.

**NOTE:** I would like to immediately intercept any advising to transform the problem to **pointer semantics** which I am well aware of. I need the solution exactly for the scheme described above.

Comment: As you already noted: have your "global set of shared pointers" count the number of used instances. When that drops to zero, dispose the pointer, hence free the memory.

Comment: This is precisely what weak pointers (`std::weak_ptr`) are for...

Comment: Sounds like featherweight object pattern.

Comment: To be more precise, it is actually called [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what your design issue is, then I would let the global set contain *weak*, non-owning pointers (e.g. `weak_ptr<>`) which are able to check if they are dangling, yet they do not increase the reference count.

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Private>> _objects;
```

Therefore, when all owning shared pointers to an object are destroyed, **the object will be** destroyed as well**.

Now your global set will be left with a dangling `weak_ptr<>`, but the nice thing is that you can *check* whether that pointer points to an object which is alive or not (use the `lock`() member function to obtain a possibly null `shared_ptr<>`. And if it doesn't, you won't dereference it:

```
// A simple, hypothetical loop through the collection of objects
// which does something, but checks whether the pointers are
// dangling before doing that something on a possibly dead object
// that would be Undefined Behavior)
std::for_each(_objects.begin(), _objecs.end(), [] (std::weak_ptr<Private> p) 
{
    std::shared_ptr<Private> sp = p.lock();
    if (sp != nullptr)
    {
        sp->callMember(); // For instance...
    }
});
```

If you also want to remove the corresponding `weak_ptr<>` to an object from the collection once the object gets destroyed, then you could use a *custom deleter* routine. Your routine will be invoked when the object is destroyed and will be passed the pointer to that object: at this point, before deallocating, you can erase the corresponding element from the set.

For example, a function that instantiates new objects of type `A` and returns a `shared_ptr` to it could look this way:

```
static std::shared_ptr<object> make_A()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Private> sp(
        new Private(),   // Instantiate the object
        [] (Private* p)  // Set up the custom deleter...
        {
            // Remove the corresponding element from the vector...
            _objects.erase(
                // ...so let's find that element!
                std::find_if( 
                    _objects.begin(),
                    _objects.end(),
                    [p] (std::weak_ptr<priv> wp)
                    {
                        // lock() will return a null pointer if wp is dangling
                        std::shared_ptr<priv> sp = wp.lock();

                        // In case wp is not dangling, return true if and only
                        // if it points to the object we're about to delete
                        return ((sp != nullptr) && (sp.get() == p));
                    })
                );
        });
}
```

Here I assumed C++11, you could easily do the same in C++03 by replacing `std::shared_ptr<>` with `boost::shared_ptr<>`, `std::weak_ptr<>` with `boost::weak_ptr<>`, and lambdas with properly-defined functors.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. Yes, you understood it correctly. The solution you proposed was the one I was thinking about too. However, I was very confused by `lock` method. Basically, it spawns new shared pointer to the object. If I call `lock` twice will it spawn 2 independent shared pointers (i.e. their reference counters are unrelated)? Or will they have shared reference counter? Indeed the first case would imply that when one of these shared pointers go out of scope the object will be deleted, which would be stupid since the other shared pointer still lives.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of when thinking about this approach. So is the second case actually the right one?

Comment: @Haroogan: I think there is no issue here. When you call `lock()`, if the object is alive, then a `shared_ptr` to that object is created. All `shared_ptr`s will share the same reference count. So this will increase the reference count. When the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, it will decrease the reference count. Not sure what you mean by "independent shared pointers": each pointer will count as an owning pointer (+1 on the ref count), but the ref count is shared by all those pointers (so if only one pointer goes out of scope, the object will still be kept alive by the second one).

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for detailed explanation, Andy, you rock :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Boost.Flyweight](http://www.boost.org/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html) out?